# Como verificar qual resultado aparecerá mais vezes em uma soma cronológica de uma sequência estabelecida?

Tags: java

Tenho essa sequência de números: `7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49`, podendo ter mais ou menos números.

Preciso somar todos eles da seguinte forma:

```
7+7=14  
14+7=21  
21+7=28  
28+7=35  
35+7=42  
42+7=49  
49+7=56
```

Esse foi o 7, faltam os outros. Todos os + 14, todos os + 21, todos os + 28, assim sucessivamente...

Exemplo:

```
7=(14,21,28,35,42,49,56)  
14=(21,28,35,42,49,56,63)  
21=(28,35,42,49,56,63,70)  
28=(35,42,49,56,63,70,77)  
35=(42,49,56,63,70,77,84)  
42=(49,56,63,70,77,84,91)  
49=(56,63,70,77,84,91,98)
```

Esses são os resultados de cada soma de todos os números, e o número que apareceu mais vezes é o "56" ou seja:

```
7+49=56  
14+42=56  
21+35=56  
28+28=56  
35+21=56  
42+12=56  
49+7=56
```

Preciso imprimir esses resultados em listas e a verificação da quantidade de números para obter o número que mais aparece nos resultados..

Imprimir Resultados:

```
7=(14,21,28,35,42,49,56)  
14=(21,28,35,42,49,56,63)  
21=(28,35,42,49,56,63,70)  
28=(35,42,49,56,63,70,77)  
35=(42,49,56,63,70,77,84)  
42=(49,56,63,70,77,84,91)  
49=(56,63,70,77,84,91,98)
```

Imprimir Verificação de quantidade:

```
14=1  
21=2  
28=3  
35=4  
42=5  
49=6  
56=7*   
63=6  
70=5  
77=4  
84=3  
91=2  
98=1
```

Imprimir Resultado Final:

A soma com o maior resultado é o número `"56".`

Tentei esse código, mas não está funcionando:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

for (long a=1; a <= 7; a++) {

long z;
z=a*7;

for (long x = z; x <= z; x++) {

long y;
y=z+x;

System.out.println(x+"="+y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Saída do programa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A saída do programa teria que sair assim:

Listas:

```
7=(14,21,28,35,42,49,56)      
14=(21,28,35,42,49,56,63)      
21=(28,35,42,49,56,63,70)  
28=(35,42,49,56,63,70,77)  
35=(42,49,56,63,70,77,84)  
42=(49,56,63,70,77,84,91)  
49=(56,63,70,77,84,91,98)
```

Verificação:

```
14=1  
21=2  
28=3  
35=4  
42=5  
49=6  
56=7*   
63=6  
70=5  
77=4  
84=3  
91=2  
98=1
```

Resultado:

```
56*
```

---

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Meu programa soma todos os números de uma determinada "sequência" com a própria sequência de números, e imprime uma lista com os resultados de cada um deles. A implementação do programa, seria a verificação dos resultados de todas as somas, ou seja, verificar a quantidade de cada resultado e imprimir a quantidade de vezes que esse resultado foi obtido, determinando assim, qual foi o resultado que apareceu mais vezes.

O programa é divido em 3 Etapas:

1. Listas
2. Verificações
3. Resultado

A 1ª Etapa está concluída:

Sequência estabelecida: `7,14,21,28,35,42,49`.

1)Listas

```
7=(14,21,28,35,42,49,56)   
14=(21,28,35,42,49,56,63)   
21=(28,35,42,49,56,63,70)   
28=(35,42,49,56,63,70,77)   
35=(42,49,56,63,70,77,84)   
42=(49,56,63,70,77,84,91)   
49=(56,63,70,77,84,91,98)
```

Já na 2ª Etapa estou tendo algumas dificuldades, não estou conseguindo passar a `Lista` que está em `Integer` para `int`, ocorre um erro nessa conversão e não funciona a verificação.

No programa em `check[z]++;` era para ser `check[lista]++;` eu deixei o `z` que são apenas os números da sequência, (7,14,21,28,35,42,49) apenas como exemplo, porque não consigo a conversão para que funcione a verificação.

Programa:

```
package etapa2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Etapa2 {

private List<Integer> lista = null;

public Etapa2(List<Integer> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}

public void soma() {
    for (Integer externo : lista) {
        System.out.print(externo + "=");
        List<String> resultado = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Integer interno : lista) {
            resultado.add(String.valueOf(interno + externo));
        }
        System.out.println("("+String.join(",", resultado)+")");  
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();

  int[] check = new int[100000000];

  for (int f=1; f<=7; f++){

      int z,p;
      z=f*7;
      lista.add(z);
      check[z]++;
    }
    Etapa2 sl = new Etapa2(lista);
    sl.soma();

    System.out.println("------------");

    int maior = 0;
    for (int i : check) {
        if (i > maior) maior = i;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= 1000000; j++) {
        if (check[j] == 0) continue;

        System.out.println(j + "=" + check[j] + (check[j] == maior ? "*" : ""));
    }      
  }
}
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vimos que a 2ª Etapa está errada, porque não está colocada a "lista" para ser verificada e sim os números da sequência apenas como exemplo.

Com a Lista no check (check[lista]++;) a saída do programa deveria ser assim:

```
7=(14,21,28,35,42,49,56)   
14=(21,28,35,42,49,56,63)   
21=(28,35,42,49,56,63,70)   
28=(35,42,49,56,63,70,77)   
35=(42,49,56,63,70,77,84)   
42=(49,56,63,70,77,84,91)   
49=(56,63,70,77,84,91,98)
```

```
14=1   
21=2   
28=3   
35=4   
42=5   
49=6   
56=7*   
63=6   
70=5  
77=4   
84=3   
91=2   
98=1
```

E a Etapa Final, colocar o resultado que apareceu mais vezes, em destaque e imprimir o número:

```
Resultado Vencedor = 56*
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é o problema que você está tentando resolver. Vejo que tem relação com a tabuada do 7 e com a soma de algarismos, mas não entendi o seu enunciado.

Comment: Olá, Felipe. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Olha, confesso que li duas vezes e ainda estou sem entender o objetivo. Até onde posso averiguar, este é justamente o problema central aqui, ou seja, não é uma questão de código, mas de definir o problema corretamente. Isto é algo fundamental para a programação: resolva o problema primeiro, depois codifique. Sem problema definido, não há como definir um algoritmo e implementá-lo corretamente.

Comment: Dito isto, na verdade eu acho que dá para entender, mas o exemplo com a sequência de múltiplos de 7 leva à entender que é uma simples progressão aritmética. O que você quer na verdade é uma matriz quadrada cujas linhas e colunas são os números da lista e os elementos são a soma do número da linha e da coluna. Depois você quer pegar o elemento mais comum. Vejo diversas aplicações matemáticas disso, embora eu esteja enferrujado demais para lembrar as terminologias exatas.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui replicar a sua saída e o seu passo-a-passo com isso:

```
class Somas7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] histograma = new int[100];
        for (int a = 1; a < 7; a++) {
            for (int b = 1; b < 7; b++) {
                histograma[7 * (a + b + 1)]++;
            }
        }
        int maior = 0;
        for (int i : histograma) {
            if (i > maior) maior = i;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            if (histograma[j] == 0) continue;
            System.out.println(j + "=" + histograma[j] + (histograma[j] == maior ? "*" : ""));
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/EreBmc)

Entretanto, sinceramente, não entendo qual é a finalidade desse programa ou qual é o problema que você quer resolver com isso.

Comment: Tudo bem Victor Stafusa, obrigado pela resposta.. mas ainda não funcionou, precisaria Imprimir primeiros os "resultados" e depois a "verificação" e assim o "resultado final", também na verificação ocorreu alguns erros, não apareceu o número 14 e o 98 e também o número 56 apareceu como resultado 6 vezes sendo que na verdade eram para ser 7 vezes...

Comment: A regulagem está de 1 para 7 mas pode ser de 1 para 100 e assim sucessivamente também... podendo assim ser qualquer número que a sequência pega-se dela mesma e soma-se esses números e imprimiria as listas e as verificações e o resulto final... dessa forma...

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi, o que você quer é fazer a combinação de todos os números da lista com eles mesmos, gerando uma espécie de matriz de soma, onde cada elemento é a soma de dois números da lista original correspondentes, respectivamente, à linha e à coluna.

Depois basta encontrar o elemento mais comum da matriz, que nada mais é do que a soma mais comum.

O segredo é que você precisa armazenar corretamente cada soma e a quantidade de vezes que ela aparece. Não dá para fazer isto com uma variável simples.

Para isto, fiz uma solução utilizando um mapa, onde cada entrada no mapa é uma soma e o valor dessa entrada é a combinação de números que totalizou na soma.

Veja o código completo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MatrixFrequentElement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //the numbers, duh
        int[] numbers = {7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49};

        //print initial matrix with sums
        printSumMatrix(numbers);
        System.out.print("\n--\n");

        //compute sums and frequency
        Result r = findMostFrequentSum(numbers);

        //print number of occurrences for each matrix entry
        printQuantities(r);
        System.out.print("\n--\n");

        //print combinations which resulted in the most frequent sum
        printSumsCombinations(r);
        System.out.print("\n--\n");

        //final result
        System.out.printf("Final result: " + r.mostFrequentNumber);

    }

    /**
     * Stores the multivalued result.
     */
    static class Result {
        final Map<Integer, List<String>> sumsByTotal;
        final int mostFrequentNumber;

        Result(Map<Integer, List<String>> sumsByTotal, int mostFrequentNumber) {
            this.sumsByTotal = sumsByTotal;
            this.mostFrequentNumber = mostFrequentNumber;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compute sums of each element in the received list with all elements of the same list (including the very element)
     * and stores the most frequent sum and how many occurrences were found.
     */
    public static Result findMostFrequentSum(final int[] numbers) {
        //sorted map whose value is the sum and value is a list of the original values which totalized the number
        final Map<Integer, List<String>> sumsByTotal = new TreeMap<>();
        final int l = numbers.length;
        int mostFrequentNumber = -1;
        int mostFrequentLength = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                final int s = numbers[i] + numbers[j];
                //get list of sums from map (or create a new one when it does not exist)
                final List<String> sums = sumsByTotal.computeIfAbsent(s, k -> new ArrayList<>());
                //add current sum
                sums.add(String.format("%d+%d", numbers[i], numbers[j]));
                //check frequency and stores most frequent
                if (mostFrequentLength == -1 || mostFrequentLength < sums.size()) {
                    mostFrequentNumber = s;
                    mostFrequentLength = sums.size();
                }
            }
        }
        return new Result(sumsByTotal, mostFrequentNumber);
    }

    /**
     * Prints each unique entry of the matrix with the number of times it showed up.
     */
    public static void printQuantities(Result r) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> e :  r.sumsByTotal.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%d=%d", e.getKey(), e.getValue().size());
            if (e.getKey() == r.mostFrequentNumber) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prints all the combinations which resulted in the most frequent sum.
     */
    public static void printSumsCombinations(Result r) {
        for (String sum : r.sumsByTotal.get(r.mostFrequentNumber)) {
            System.out.printf("%s=%d%n", sum, r.mostFrequentNumber);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prints a matrix whose values are a sum of two numbers from the received list corresponding to the row and column.
     */
    public static void printSumMatrix(final int[] numbers) {
        final int l = numbers.length;

        //print first empty cell
        System.out.print("+\t\t");
        //print row with headers
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t", numbers[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        //separating row
        System.out.print("\t\t");
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            System.out.print("--\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        //print other rows
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            //first column is a header as well
            System.out.printf("%d\t=\t", numbers[i]);
            //print rest ot the row with sums
            for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                final int s = numbers[i] + numbers[j];
                System.out.printf("%d\t", s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

A saída gerada é:

```
+       7   14  21  28  35  42  49  
        --  --  --  --  --  --  --  
7   =   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  
14  =   21  28  35  42  49  56  63  
21  =   28  35  42  49  56  63  70  
28  =   35  42  49  56  63  70  77  
35  =   42  49  56  63  70  77  84  
42  =   49  56  63  70  77  84  91  
49  =   56  63  70  77  84  91  98  

--
14=1
21=2
28=3
35=4
42=5
49=6
56=7*
63=6
70=5
77=4
84=3
91=2
98=1

--
7+49=56
14+42=56
21+35=56
28+28=56
35+21=56
42+14=56
49+7=56

--
Final result: 56
```

Note que eu fiz um adicional, que é exibir as combinações numéricas que geraram a soma mais frequente. Isto acabou adicionando um pouco de complexidade no código porque precisei armazenar uma lista com tais combinações no mapa.

Se não precisa disso, remove o lance da lista e use valores inteiros no mapa para representar a quantidade, ao invés de usar o tamanho da lista como eu fiz.