# Como imprimir uma lista com o resultado de todos os números de uma sequência somados com ela mesma? (sequência)

Tags: java

Tenho essa sequência de números: 1,2,3. (Podendo ser de 1 ao infinito.)

Quero somar cada número da sequência com ela toda, exemplo:

A sequência tem 3 números.

É preciso somar dessa forma:

```
(1)  
1+1=2  
1+2=3  
1+3=4  

(2)  
2+1=3  
2+2=4  
2+3=5 

(3)  
3+1=4  
3+2=5  
3+3=6
```

O programa deve imprimir a lista com os resultados de cada número da sequência separadamente:

1=(2,3,4)
2=(3,4,5)
3=(4,5,6)

Comment: A [resposta do victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212324/28595) já parece fazer isso. Ela não atendeu?

Comment: Boa Tarde @diegofm, a saída do programa não "imprimi" a "lista" com "todos" os "resultados" das "somas" de cada "número" da "sequência".

Comment: @diegofm o programa do Victor faz uma verificação de qual resultado aparece mais vezes nas somas dos números de uma sequência com ela mesma mas não imprimi uma lista com os resultados das somas de cada número da sequência com ela mesma...

Comment: @FelipeCortez a idéia do Stackoverflow é ajudar a resolver bugs e encontrar workarounds para problemas, e não fazer sua tarefa da escola!

Comment: Desculpe @I'mBlueDaBaDee mas não estou fazendo tarefa de escola. Estou tentando construir um programa mas não consigo e estou pedindo ajuda, apenas isso... Não fique com raiva ou bravo comigo se você não pode me ajudar, eu posso te ajudar, vou te ajudar te dando um conselho: Olhe, ajude seu próximo enquanto você ainda pode, enquanto você ainda tem tempo, porque uma hora todo esse nosso tempo aqui acaba, e no final das contas todos nós se arrependemos do que não fizemos e poderíamos ter feito... E quando é que vamos ter a certeza disso tudo? Só lá no outro lado da vida... Até mais amigo...

Comment: Qual linguagem estás tentando implementar? javascript, java, python, c++, ruby ou todas? O que você já tentou? Qual erro deu?

Comment: @FelipeCortez em nenhum momento deixei minha cordialidade ao aborda-lo, foi um comentário sobre o quão **trivial** é a sua pergunta, o que faz **parecer** com que seja um **trabalho de escola**, se você deseja **não** passar essa impressão, mostre o contexto do que você está fazendo, qual seu objetivo com tal funcionalidade. At.te. Lucas Gabriel da Costa.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como verificar qual resultado aparecerá mais vezes em uma soma cronológica de uma sequência estabelecida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212317/como-verificar-qual-resultado-aparecer%c3%a1-mais-vezes-em-uma-soma-cronol%c3%b3gica-de-um)

Comment: caramba, teve os dom dos downvote sem ter a pergunta fechada, novo achievment

Comment: Boa noite @diegofm vou deixar o link com a atualização do programa: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212317/como-verificar-qual-resultado-aparecer%C3%A1-mais-vezes-em-uma-soma-cronol%C3%B3gica-de-um]

Comment: Boa noite @I'mBlueDaBaDee, segue o link com a atualização do programa: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212317/como-verificar-qual-resultado-aparecer%C3%A1-mais-vezes-em-uma-soma-cronol%C3%B3gica-de-um]

Comment: Boa noite @Fabiano, estou implementando o programa em Java, está quase concluído vou deixar o link da atualização, obrigado pela ajuda... [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212317/como-verificar-qual-resultado-aparecer%C3%A1-mais-vezes-em-uma-soma-cronol%C3%B3gica-de-um]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que este exemplo faz o que você precisa. A classe recebe a lista de elementos no construtor. O método soma itera duas vezes de forma aninhada pela lista e imprime o resultado.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SomaLista {

    private List<Integer> lista = null;

    public SomaLista(List<Integer> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public void soma() {
        for (Integer externo : lista) {
            System.out.print(externo + "=");
            List<String> resultado = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Integer interno : lista) {
                resultado.add(String.valueOf(interno + externo));
            }
            System.out.println("("+String.join(",", resultado)+")");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      for (int i=1; i<=1000000; i++){
  lista.add(i);
        }
        SomaLista sl = new SomaLista(lista);
        sl.soma();
    }

}
```

Comment: Boa Tarde @fsola, muito obrigado é quase isso!! está praticamente 90%.. O único problema é que a lista como ai está é de 1 a 3.. e se for de 1 a 1.000.000 ficaria complicado ter que colocar um a um.. teria que ser algo como um array.. Como fazer tudo isso que você fez, com um array que tivesse a regulagem que quisesse?

Comment: Coloque o lista.add dentro de um for até 1000000.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!! Consegui colocar a lista em um for... era isso!!!

Comment: Boa noite @fsola, eu atualizei minha primeira pergunta para incluir uma implementação no programa: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212317/como-verificar-qual-resultado-aparecer%C3%A1-mais-vezes-em-uma-soma-cronol%C3%B3gica-de-um#212317]